# Why does VScode say SDL.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, sdl, header-files, include-path

I have the SDL "include" folder inside my workspace, and while typing the code visual studio seems to recognize that the file exists. But whenever I try running it, I get this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmqoB.png)

I have tried directly including the SDL library I downloaded, in case I was missing some files that are need for it to work. No matter what way I organise the files and the 'include' config, it refuses to recognize the file while running

Comment: (a) `#include` with the `<…>` form says to include from “system” folders. Folders inside your workspace are not system folders. There may be configuration options to tell the compiler to search for “system” headers inside your workspace. (b) Having the SDL include folder inside your workspace is insufficient to cause a search for “SDL.h” to find it there. You might need a full path relative to your workspace, such as “SDL/include/SDL.h”, or you might need to configure your compiler to search for headers in the folder, “SDL/include”.

Comment: Welcome to SO. How did you try to add include folder? Which json file did you adjust? That message comes from the compiler, not from VSCode. VSCode include path settings don't matter.

Comment: BTW please don't show pictures of text. Instead cooy&paste the message as formatted text directly into the question.

Answer (score 0):

While you compile your code you have to specify include directories that are different from the defaults. You can do this by compiling with the -I flag. For example:
`gcc main.c -o main -I./include`
As for Intellisense, there should be an Include Directories setting in the C/C++ extension you are using.

If you are using tasks here is what I've used for compiling my homework for my university assignment that used SDL2: [Github Gist link for my `tasks.json`](https://gist.github.com/nevemlaci/9833bf8fb1bc25325ba10e4acc326b0e)